# ImageMagick Append multiple images together side by side

Tags: image, merge, append, imagemagick, photos

I am a newb to ImageMagick and my end goal is to append many images together, side by side, into a final single JPEG image.

I am using the Append command as instructed in this thread : [Link](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=11320)

I just installed ImageMagick on OSX 10.10.5 Yosemite. I place the original images I'd like to append, (image1.jpg, image2.jpg), in the computer home folder.

I use this code
CODE:

> convert image1.jpg image2.jpg +append output.jpg

I get this error readout.

**convert: no decode delegate for this image format `JPEG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
convert: unable to open image 'image2jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3094.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
convert: no images defined `output.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3254.**

I read that I may not have the correct JPEG delegate? I downloaded the jpegsrc.v9a.tar.gz delegate file. Do I have to add this to the library? If so how can I do this?

Do I have to put the original images in a certain directory?

Thanks a lot fo your help,

Henry

Comment: How did you install ImageMagick? If from source, then you need to install all the needed delegates (such as for jpg) before installing ImageMagick. This is a real pain. You should just install a binary. Unfortunately, the only Mac binary provided by ImageMagick is for El Capitan. I would recommend that you either install ImageMagick from MacPorts or Homebrew. That way you get all the needed delegates. You can also install all your delegates from MacPorts and then install ImageMagick from source. Your command is correct, if all image are in the same directory as where you issue your command

Comment: As fmw42 said, you can use Homebrew to install ImageMagick:
1) Install brew https://brew.sh 2) brew install imagemagick